# Consistently slow to display first Manipulate on Mma launch

Tags: manipulate, front-end

Since Mathematica 10.1 I've suffered a significant wait time whenever I **display** my first `Manipulate` after launch Mathematica on my Macbook [running OS X, El Capitain and Sierra and after reinstalls].

On fresh launch:

```
start = AbsoluteTime[];
dontDisplay = Manipulate[x, {x, 1, 10}];
difference = AbsoluteTime[] - start
(*0.001352*)
```

Then I display `manipulate` and it takes over 10s:

```
start = AbsoluteTime[];
dontDisplay
difference = AbsoluteTime[] - start
(*11.132718*)
```

The issue does not rear its ugly head if I `Quit[]` my kernel, and every subsequent Manipulate displays as quickly as expected.

Intriguingly, if on first launch I go to the documentation for Manipulate then all the pre-generated `Manipulate` display quickly and are interactive. But I still get the 10+ second wait time if I generate a new Manipulate myself.

Happy to contact support regarding this but I've not been following issues with Mathematica closely since 10.1 and anticipated this may have been encountered by other users or there might be an undocumented way of fixing this situation.

Selected system information:

```
{"Version" -> "11.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (July 28, 2016)", "ReleaseID" -> "11.0.0.0 (5570718, 2016072801)", "MachineType" -> "PC", "OperatingSystem" -> "MacOSX", "ProcessorType" -> "x86-64","DefaultCCompiler" -> Missing["NotActive"], "CCompilers" -> Missing["NotActive"], "SystemID" -> "MacOSX-x86-64", "CommandLine" -> {"/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/WolframKernel", "-wstp", "-mathlink", "-linkprotocol", "SharedMemory", "-linkconnect", "-linkname","2sz59_shm"}, "WSTPVersion" -> "4.25 (2016041001)", "ProcessorCount" -> 2, "SystemMemory" -> 17179869184, "LicenseSubprocesses" -> 0, "MaxLicenseSubprocesses" -> 16, "EvaluatorName" -> "Local", "EvaluatorNames" -> {"Local"}}
```

Comment: Did you mean `dontdisplay` instead of `manipulate` ?

Comment: I suspect the FE is loading resources the first time.  I seem to have only a 0.5 sec delay in 10.{2,3,4} (Mac OSX).  I also have the start-up dialog and the SE palette loaded automatically, which may load some of the resources needed in the `Manipulate`.

Comment: I have only 1 sec delay the first time i display Manipulate ... (OSX 10.9.5, v10.3.1 & v11.0.0) that's why I've never noticed that before.

Comment: @SquareOne - fixed, thanks. Up to 1 second delay is ok, 10+ seconds makes it feel like the world is melting around me. I'm unsure why displaying the pre-generated `Manipulate`s in the documentation don't load the necessary resources?